# <P> tag is converted in to span tag automatically in my wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

In my site I am using visual composer in my word press site.Here the `p` tag is converted into `span` tag automatically. When I inspect my site using inspect element in Mozilla fire bug I see `span` tag and when I edit it into `P` tag my problem get solved.  But I don't understand why `<p>` tag is converted into `span` tag automatically

Here is what I see in inspect element

```
<span style="padding:0 8px;">Best app to sign PDF Files.</span>
```

This cause a  White block on my page. And when I change this to

```
<p style="padding:0 8px;">Best app to sign PDF Files.</p>
```

This, it solves my problem but I don't understand why it changes to span tag automatically.

Comment: I don't use Visual Composer, but when I read your question, it look like the filter wpautop has been disabled and  replaced with a function that replace P tag with  span instead of insert P tag. Usually, you can prevent this behaviour by remove the filter. What the method used, when you say you edit it into P tag my problem get solved. ? Did you investigate around action and filter like save_post ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style is set in a javascript file, you'll need to find it. Press `Ctrl` + `U`, next `Ctrl` + `F`, type the `.js` and you will see all connected javascript files. You need to open each file and also, `Ctrl` + `F` and enter the `padding:`.

Comment: what and where should i search the file??

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed, go to the page on your site where you want to remove the padding, and make all the instructions which I wrote to you earlier. Sorry for my mistakes, if there is, I am writing to you with the help of google translate

Comment: you mean from file zila or front end of the site.. I think I should change it from backend and not in front end. So in backend  which file should i open.

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed, in front end of you will find it, and edit already be in the back end. If you want, I can help you find it.

Comment: yes please can you help me out in solving this problem

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed, I can get a link to your site?